# How to fix "cannot access ActivityCompat class file for android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat not found" error in android?

Tags: java, android

I encounter an error in my android project stating `cannot access ActivityCompat class file for android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat not found`. How do I possibly fix this? Below my logcat.

> F:/hamza/Inspection Android App/QA Code (April 2019)/urgent Folder 30 April 2019/QAInshpection 
>   app/src/main/java
>   android/itgdeveloper/com/qainshpection/classes/AQLEntry.java
>   error: cannot access ActivityCompat
>   class file for android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat not found
>   error: cannot access SupportActivity
>   class file for android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity not found 
>   error: cannot access RequestPermissionsRequestCodeValidator
>   class file for android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$RequestPermissionsRequestCodeValidator not found
>   error: cannot find symbol variable super
>   error: cannot find symbol method getAssets()
>   error: cannot find symbol variable this 
>   error: cannot find symbol method getIntent()
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method startActivity(Intent)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: not an enclosing class: AQLEntry 
>   error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   error: not an enclosing class: AQLEntry 
>   error: not an enclosing class: AQLEntry 
>   error: cannot find symbol variable this 
>   error: not an enclosing class: AQLEntry 
>   error: not an enclosing class: AQLEntry 
>   error: not an enclosing class: AQLEntry 
>   error: an enclosing instance that contains AQLEntry.po_listAdapter1 is required 
>   error: not an enclosing class: AQLEntry 
>   error: not an enclosing class: AQLEntry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not added the support library, please add support library com.android.support:support-v4.

**Steps:**

Add the following line to your app/build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:YOUR_TARGET_VERSION'
```

replace the YOUR_TARGET_VERSION with your target version,
Eg:-

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

And rebuild the project.

Comment: these lines already include in my gradle 

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
but with 27.1.1